# 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, label

```
def make_label(path, dict_vuln2testcase, _type):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    context = f.read().split('------------------------------')[:-1]
    f.close()

    context[0] = '\n' + context[0]

    list_all_label = []
    list_all_vulline = []
    for _slice in context:
        vulline = []
        index_line = _slice.split('\n')[1] 
        list_codes = _slice.split('\n')[2:-1] 
        case_name = index_line.split(' ')[1]
        key_name = '/'.join(index_line.split(' ')[1].split('/')[-2:])
        print index_line

        if key_name in dict_vuln2testcase.keys():
        list_codeline = [code.split(' ')[-1] for code in list_codes]
        dicti = dict_vuln2testcase[key_name]

        _dict_cwe2line_target = {}
        _dict_cwe2line = {}
        dicto = dicti
for _dict in dicto: 
                for key in _dict.keys():
                    if _dict[key] not in _dict_cwe2line_target.keys():
                        _dict_cwe2line_target[_dict[key]] = [key] 
                    else:
                        _dict_cwe2line_target[_dict[key]].append(key)


                for line in list_codeline:
                    line = line.strip()
                    if line in _dict.keys():
                        if not ' '.join((list_codes[list_codeline.index(line)].strip()).split(' ')[:-1]) == dict_testcase2code[key_name+"/"+line].strip():
                            continue
                        cweid = _dict[line]
                        vulline.append(list_codeline.index(line))

                        if cweid not in _dict_cwe2line.keys():
                            _dict_cwe2line[cweid] = [line]
                        else:
                            _dict_cwe2line[cweid].append(line)

                if _type:
                 list_vuln_cwe = []
                 for key in _dict_cwe2line.keys():
                    if key == 'Any...':
                        continue
                    if len(_dict_cwe2line[key]) == len(_dict_cwe2line_target[key]):
                        label_cwe = []
                        label_cwe = get_label_cwe(key, label_cwe)
                        list_vuln_cwe += label_cwe
                else:
                 list_vuln_cwe = []
                for key in _dict_cwe2line.keys():
                    if key == 'Any...':
                        continue
                    label_cwe = []
                    label_cwe = get_label_cwe(key, label_cwe)
                    list_vuln_cwe += label_cwe

                if list_vuln_cwe == []:
                 list_label = [0] * len(label_vec_type)
                else:
                 list_vuln_cwe = list(set(list_vuln_cwe))
                 list_label = get_label_veclist(list_vuln_cwe)

        else:
            list_label = [0] * len(label_vec_type)

        list_all_label.append(list_label)
        list_all_vulline.append(vulline)

    return list_all_label, list_all_vulline


def main():
    f = open("dict_flawline2filepath.pkl", 'rb')
    dict_vuln2testcase = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    _type = False
    time = '4'
    lang = 'C/test_data/' + time

    path = os.path.join(lang, 'api_slices.txt')
    list_all_apilabel, list_all_vulline = make_label(path, dict_vuln2testcase, _type)
```

i got this error :

```
1 /home/user/project/joern-0.3.1/mytestcode/NVD/CVE-2010-2068/CVE_2010_2068_PATCHED_ap_proxy_http_process_response.c sscanf 122
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_label.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "make_label.py", line 134, in main
    list_all_apilabel, list_all_vulline = make_label(path, dict_vuln2testcase, _type)
  File "make_label.py", line 71, in make_label
    for _dict in dict: 
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

How to Solve it?? where i have to change this typeerror?? Please tell why this error occurs!!!I am not able to change this error. I had tried so many ways to change this error!! Actually this program tries to make label for the vulnerable piece of code which i had given input for the python program.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: change the variable name. dict is a data-type and you can't use it for variable names

Comment: @quamrana when not using global i am gettng this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dicti' referenced before assignment

Comment: @SiGNoR when i changed the name of dict to dicti i got the following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dicti' referenced before assignment

Comment: Just pass `dicti` in as another parameter.

Comment: you should change all occurrences of "dict" to dicti, and see the "dicti" is defined under your "make_label" function

Comment: @quamrana i just give dicto = dicti but i got the same error!!

Comment: @SiGNoR yes i changed it!! but gettin the same error

Comment: please edit and update your code in post, that we can see the changes in your code and new Error

Comment: @SiGNoR I have updated my code. please look upon it. I go this code from github.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `dict` into your function:

```
def make_label(path, dict_vuln2testcase, _type, dicti):
    # most contents elided

    # typical usage:
    for _dict in dicti:

def main():
    f = open("dict_flawline2filepath.pkl", 'rb')
    # details elided

    dicti = {}

    list_all_apilabel, list_all_vulline = make_label(path, dict_vuln2testcase, _type, dicti)
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. now the program is running without any error!!